# How to solve an integral inside a summation (with a divergent term)

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, summation, kronecker-delta

I have a question that might be silly, but I really don't understand what is going on. I have to solve the following integral:

$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{m}^{m+1}e^{inx}dx $$

However if we try to solve it in normal fashion, its solution is divergent when $n=0$. The solution in the paper that I am reading is:

$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{m}^{m+1}e^{inx}dx =  \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\delta_{n,0} + \frac{1-\delta_{n,0}}{in} \left(e^{in(m+1)}-e^{in(m)}\right) $$

However I think that the second term on the RHS is still divergent in $n=0$. Moreover, I do understand that the $\delta^{'}$s are introduced as an identity to cure the divergence, but I really don't understand how that is equal to the LHS.

Hopefully you can give me some insight :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean divergent for $n=0$ - the summand is just $1$ since $\delta_{0,0}=1$. $n$ is just the summation index.

Comment: So I think I used the wrong word. It is undefined, because at $n=0$ the denominator in $\frac{1-\delta}{ in}$ is zero. I thought the solution was only the term $\frac{e^{in(m+1)}-e^{in(m)}}{in}$. I don't understand why I need to add the $\delta$'s there, I thought the deltas are required to "cure" the case when n=0 but I don't see clearly why.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess I'll spell it out completely.

$$S_m=\sum_{n\in\Bbb{Z}}\int_{m}^{m+1}e^{inx}\mathrm{d}x$$
If $n=0$, the integrand is just $1$. In other words
$$\int_{m}^{m+1}e^{i\cdot0\cdot x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{m}^{m+1}1\mathrm{d}x=m+1-m=1.$$
Otherwise,
$$\int_m^{m+1}e^{inx}\mathrm{d}x=\left(\frac{e^{inx}}{in}\right)\bigg|^{m+1}_m=\frac{e^{in(m+1)}-e^{inm}}{in}$$
So our sum can be written as
$$S_m=1+\sum_{n\in\Bbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}}\frac{e^{in(m+1)}-e^{inm}}{in}$$
The sum given in your question is
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\delta_{n,0} + (1-\delta_{n,0})\frac{e^{in(m+1)}-e^{inm}}{in}  $$
The zero term is
$$\delta_{0,0}+(1-\delta_{0,0})\cdot(...)=1-(1-1)\cdot(...)=1$$
And the other terms are
$$\delta_{n,0}+(1-\delta_{n,0})\frac{e^{in(m+1)}-e^{in(m)}}{in}=\frac{e^{in(m+1)}-e^{inm}}{in}$$
So the sum is
$$S_m=1+\sum_{n\in\Bbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}}\frac{e^{in(m+1)}-e^{inm}}{in}.$$
Anything unclear?